# Angularjs ng-repeat filter by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

hi i have 2 tables in mysql, i call the data with php(mysqli), so i put this data in javascript var with   `$scope.student= <?php echo json_encode( $student) ?>;` and `$scope.ratings= <?php echo json_encode( $ratings) ?>;` 2 tables have a key id(ID_studen)

The first table have only a personal data, and the second have datails, so i need filter and show all details by ratings here code:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="student in students">
   <li ng-repeat="rating in ratings (where student.tagid =ratings.tagid">  {{rating.note}}</li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

check [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/8na3tecv/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $filter please see demo below

```js
app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("Ctrl", Ctrl);

function Ctrl($scope) {

  $scope.students = [{
    firstname: 'Buster',
    lastname: 'Bluth',
    tagid: '4134'
  }, {
    firstname: 'John',
    lastname: 'McClane',
    tagid: '9845'
  }, {
    firstname: 'Mister',
    lastname: 'Spock',
    tagid: '0905'
  }];

  $scope.ratings = [{
    matter: 'Mathematics',
    note: '12',
    tagid: '4134'
  }, {
    matter: 'Biology',
    note: '13',
    tagid: '9845'
  }, {
    matter: 'Lenguage:',
    note: '14',
    tagid: '0905'
  }];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="student in students">
    <li ng-repeat="rating in ratings | filter : {tagid: student.tagid}">{{student.firstname}} {{student.lastname}} | {{rating.matter}} {{rating.tagid}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="student in students">
        <li ng-repeat="rating in ratings | { tagid = student.tagid }">{{rating.note}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the actual way to do inline filtering on a property:

```
<li ng-repeat="rating in ratings | filter: {'tagid': student.tagid}">  {{rating.note}}</li>
```

However note that is is more performant to pre-filter your result list, so in your controller you would put

```
$scope.filteredRatings = $scope.ratings.filter(function(r) {
    return r.tagid === $scope.student.tagid;
});
```

So your html would only be:

```
<li ng-repeat="rating in filteredRatings">  {{rating.note}}</li>
```

Finally, I'm not very comfortable with php but it sounds like a weird way to populate your model. You should do it in the actual javascript file and not within your HTML.

Comment: i use php only for load data from DB, that is bad?